# Proportionals and squares

Tags: number-theory

Let $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z^+}$
and
$a:b::c:d$
and
$ac$ is a square.
Can we prove that $bd$ is a square too?

Comment: You mean that the four integers are square ? Or $a : b :: c : d$ denotes anything special ?

Comment: We have $\dfrac ba=\dfrac dc\implies ?$

Comment: $a,b,c,d$ are positive integers, and the product $ac$ is a square number. We want to prove that the product of $bd$ is a square as well.

Comment: What is $a:b$ ?

And $a::b$ ?

Comment: $a:b::c:d$ means that the four numbers are proportional: as $a$ is to $b$ so $c$ is do $d$.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So it is only for saying that $bc=ad$, no ?

Comment: Yeah, that's a consequence since $a:b::c:d$

Comment: Yes but $bc=ad$ is a notation that everyone gets.

$a:b::c:d$ is not so obvious for everyone. I'm pretty sure the notation is not known in France and probably in one great part of Europa...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$bd=\frac{bcd}{c}=\frac{a}{c}.d^2=\frac{ac}{c^2}. d^2 =ac. (\frac{d}{c})^2$

Write $ac=e^2$.

Then $bd= (\frac{ed}{c})^2=x^2$

It shows that $bd$ is the square of a rational $x=\frac{de}{c}$.

It shows that this is the square of a rational but we know that $bd$ is an integer.

But we have the following result :

If $x$ is a rational and $x^2$ an integer, $x$ is an integer. (I prove it in five minutes).

For the result, write $x=\frac{p}{q}$ with $\gcd(p,q)=1$. Then, $\frac{p^2}{q^2}$ is an integer so $q^2$ divides $p^2$. But $\gcd(p^2,q^2)=1$, so it follows that $q=1$, and $x=p$ is an integer.

Comment: Can you prove that the product of 2 squares is also a square?

Comment: $x^2.y^2=(x.y)^2$

Comment: Yeah, and can you prove that?

Comment: $x.x.y.y=x.(xy).y=x.(yx).y=xy.xy=(xy)^2$

Comment: Well, I have a counter example that $d/c$ is not always an integer, let's take 2,3,8,12 & $2:3::8:12$ and $2.8=16$ and as you can see $d/c$ is not an integer.

Comment: Sorry, I was not speaking of $\frac{d}{c}$, but $\frac{d}{c}.\sqrt{ac}$

Answer (score 2):

We have $ad=bc$.  It follows that $adbc$ is a square. Since $ac$ is a square, so is $bd$.

There is a gap in this argument. We must show that if $xy$ is a square and $x$ is a square then $y$ is a square.  A straightforward way to fill the gap is to use the fact that $w$ is a square if and only if in the prime power factorization $\prod p_i^{e_i}$ of $w$, every exponent $e_i$ is even.

If every exponent in the prime power factorization of $x$ is even, and some exponent in the prime power factorization of $y$ is odd, then some exponent in the prime power factorization of $xy$ would be odd, contradicting the fact that $xy$ is a square.